# openresty and per-server (or per-script) user

Tags: nginx, openresty

I'm with very simple question:
Do openresty supports to run different servers or maybe scripts with different user accounts?

While nginx itself maybe safe and there's no need for multiple accounts, with programming language it can became very useful... php-fpm supports it out-of-box plus it can be achievable running it just with different configs. other apps, for example, nodejs, runs under its own user accounts. What is good practice with openresty? Also run multiple instances with different configs?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: Openresty is "an nginx on steroids". So everything you are getting from nginx itself will be included in openresty.</sup>

To you initial questions:

- No, there is no built-in function to let nginx run in multiple user contexts.
- The good practice is to secure you providing entitites. See below.
- Yes, you can run mutiple instances of nginx. But you cannot (easily) bind a single (externally reachable) Port to multiple instances.

---

Since `nginx` can be considered safe <sup>*[citation needed]* ;)</sup>, there is no need to run it in different contexts. It already runs in its **own context** (depending on your system, most likely `nginx`, `www-data`, or `httpd`). Your providing entity (may it be php-fpm, NodeJS, python, Go, etc.) is the place to take measures for safety. Top measure, as mentioned, is to run these with different users. Most, if not all, fpm providers will do that by default. Only if you run an application yourself (that provides an http-endpoint), you have to take care about that. I'm sure most documentions of the suoftware in use will provide information about running the software in its own, secure context.

The nginx is (only) a reverse-proxy for those entities that delivers the data to the end user (and receives as well). So it has a gate function and has to have a solid configuration (there a multiple catches in [php-fpm config for example](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-11043)), but is secure to run in a single user-context.

Note²: Openresty is mighty and can execute JavaScript and Lua scripts on the fly. So if those are in use, the rules of this game change significantly.